# Why std::vector::resize works like this with matrix of objects

Tags: c++, stdvector

This is the code to reproduce what I'm trying to understand:

First I have a class with a pointer as attribute and its contructor set to default.

```
class PointExampl {
private:
    int* p_ = new int;

public:
    PointExampl() = default;
    int* returnp() {return p_;};
};
```

This is the main.cpp:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<PointExampl>> vec;
    vec.resize(10, std::vector<PointExampl>(10));

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vec[i][0].returnp() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

`0x1695c8e1920`

So this is what i dont get about std::resize .
Shouldn't every first object of every row have a different pointer?

This is simplification of a problem that i got using std::vector for some class project about game of life.
I was expecting to have a full matrix of new pointers but instead got a copy of the first row pointers to the other rows.

also im using c++14 if that has anything to do about it.

Comment: You haven't supplied copy/move constructors or assignment operators for `PointExampl`.  The default generated versions of those functions copies pointers by value, and won't dynamically allocate new values of `p_`.    Look up "rule of three" (before C++11) or "rule of five" (C++11 and later) for why this is a concern, and approach to deal with it.

Answer (score 5):

From cppreference on [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) (emphasis mine)

> **Resizes the container to contain `count` elements.**
> If the current size is greater than count, the container is reduced to its first count elements.
> **If the current size is less than `count`,**
>
> 1. additional default-inserted elements are appended
> 2. **additional copies of `value` are appended.**

Because you chose the second overload (one taking a value), it will copy the `value` (which is `std::vector<PointExampl>`) `count` times, which in turn means that it will make copies of elements inside vector.

It may be solved by actually making each vector (in a loop):

```
    std::vector<std::vector<PointExampl>> vec;
    vec.reserve(10); //optional
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        vec.emplace_back(10); //not the clearest code, push_back would be easier to read but a tiny bit slower
```

Or with an algorithm like [`std::generate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate), returning a new vector for each element. ***However***, the proper solution would be to add a copy constructor (since your class manages a resource), and, consequntially, the [Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

```
class PointExampl {
private:
    int* p_ = new int;

public:
    PointExampl() = default;
    PointExampl(const PointExampl& other) { 
        p_ = new int; 
        *p_ = *(other.p_);
    }
    PointExampl(PointExampl&& other) { 
        p_ = other.p_;
        other.p_ = nullptr;
    }
    PointExampl& operator= (const PointExampl& other) {
        *p_ = *other.p_;
        return *this;
    }
    PointExampl& operator= (PointExampl&& other) {
        if(this != &other) {
            delete p_;
            p_ = other.p_;
            other.p_ = nullptr;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    ~PointExampl() { delete p_; }
    int* returnp() {return p_;};
};
```

It's a crude example, and it certianly could be done better (e.g. using copy and swap idiom), but for the sake of simplicity it should do.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<PointExampl>(10)` creates a vector with 10 brand new, default constructed `PointExampl` objects, each with different pointers.

`vec.resize(10, std::vector<PointExampl>(10));` takes that vector and copies it 10 times to the outer vector, meaning that every *row* in the top level vector is a copy of the same one, hence the identital 0th pointers.

The solution depends on what you're trying to achieve. You could perform new allocations when a `PointExampl` is copied by providing a copy constructor, or disable copy construction and individually create each element and `push_back`/`insert` to the appropriate vectors.